# How to sum/count the total number of occurrence of particular string or pattern in Grafana-Loki

Tags: grafana-loki

In Grafana,
I am searching for total no of occurance of particualr string / pattern like below
{k8s_cluster="mycluster", namespace="mynamespace", app="myappname"} |= `Event received: Type myevent, Key` |= `\"sourceSystem\":\"mysystem\"` | json

Now I need to get the sum/total count of this pattern present in logs say in last 1 hour or two hour.

I tried to use count over time and sum but I am not seeing the same count so I need help to achieve this.
If I simply searches in last oone hour without any aggregiation in logs I can see 200 or 300 occurances but  if it is more than 1000 it wont comes so I need to get the count/sum so need aggrigation function to work on this.

Comment: Show exactly the query you tried, and explain how it fails you explanation.